# Php array iteration with conditional indexing

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm working on PHP array iteration. I have arrays for example as below : 
1) banned  2) age

```
$banned = array(
       "school_name"=> "abc",
       "school_rating"=> "xyz",  
);

$age = array(
       "Peter"=> "35",   // 0
       "Ben"=> "16",     // 1
       "Joe"=> "43"      // 2
       "john"=> "12",    // 3
);
```

I'm iterating over this array using foreach :

```
foreach($age as $index => $value) {
    if ($value < '18') {
         $banned['name_' . $index] = $value; // Push values below 18 to 'banned' array with index value
    }

}
```

I want to find names which are below age 18 & push theme to `'banned'` array.

This code works correct. But while pushing names to `'banned'` array, I want to append new index to their names such as `'Ben_0'`  `'john_1'`.

Current code appending `index` as per foreach iteration such as `'Ben_1'`  `'john_3'`.

I want my final array to like :

```
$banned = array(
       "school_name"=> "abc",
       "school_rating"=> "xyz",       
       "Ben_0"=> "16",     
       "john_1"=> "12",   
);
```

I want this new indexing in order to perform some API call later.

So is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: `$banned = array_filter($age, function($var) { return $var['age'] < 18; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($age as $index => $value) {
    if ($value < '18') {
         $banned[$index . '_' . $count++] = $value; // Push values below 18 to 'banned' array with index value
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$i = 0;    
foreach($age as $index => $value) 
{
        if ($value < '18') {
             $banned['name_' . $i] = $value; // Push values below 18 to 'banned' array with index value
             $i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($age as $name => $age)
{
    $banned[$name . '_' . $i++] = $age;
}
```